# The fixed point iteration to solve x

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

For part a, can I just substitute both $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ with x and then solve the equation? And any thoughts on part b? Thank you guys!

Comment: Most likely that book has something like the Banach's fixed point theorem which you need to absorb.

Comment: @Moo It is not form a book. I think our professor wrote this question.

Comment: @OskarLimka Not really, the previous chapter talks about bisection method and this chapter talks about the fixed point iteration. That's it.

Comment: Solving x? I substituted $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ with x and I solved the equation. Is that correct? For part b, can u give me more hints? How to find the convergence rate for it?

Comment: $x=\left(-x^2-c\right)\div 2b$

Comment: $x=\pm \sqrt {b^2-c}-b$. I think I am fine with part a, can you talk more about part b? I have no idea how to find the convergence

Comment: This is a quadratic equation with $a = 0$. Now, using fixed point iteration, how do you find convergence?

Comment: Take derivatives?

Comment: @J.doe the error is $\epsilon_n:=|x-x_n|$ where $x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, the required error estimate means that for some $c$ independent of $n$ we have $$\epsilon_n\leq c2^{-n}.$$  A sufficient condition for this to happen is that for some $N\geq1$, $$\epsilon_n\leq\frac12\epsilon_{n-1}.$$  Yet another sufficient condition to satisfy the latter is that the iteration reduces distances by a half $$|g(x)-g(y)|\leq\frac12|x-y|$$ (you should understand why this is sufficient and make sure you can write $g(x)$.) Finally, using the mean value theorem should give you the final sufficient condition.

Comment: but what about b?